# Can .NET implicitly find out one type parameter from another?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-parameter

We've got a base class for most of our domain object:

```
public class AbstractEntity<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for example, I've got class `MobileOperator : AbstractEntity<int>`.

What I want to do is to write generic equality comparer for all AbstractEntity descendants. And I want to create it like that:

```
var comparer = new AbstractEntityComparer<MobileOperator>();
```

I declare this comparer as following:

```
public class AbstractEntityEqualityComparer<TAbstractEntity, TId> : IEqualityComparer<TAbstractEntity>
    where TAbstractEntity : AbstractEntity<TId>
```

However, in this case I must explicitly tell the compiler that TId = int: `new AbstractEntityComparer<MobileOperator, int>()`. And if I put, say, `long` instead of `int`, it just wont compile. So, definitely, the compiler has a way to determine which type I use to create MobileOperator.

So is it possible to write comparer in a way that won't make me write this redundant `int` thing all the time? And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: No, that's not possible. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171067/no-type-inference-with-generic-extension-method/7171527#7171527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# doesn't do type inference based on constraints, so you need the explicit generic construction. See the [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) by Eric Lippert for the details (and also an argument in the comments about why he's wrong wrong wrong.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179460/why-generic-extension-method-with-constraint-is-not-recognized-as-extension-metho/7179754#7179754 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171067/no-type-inference-with-generic-extension-method/7171527#7171527