# How to create an extension method with the same signature but different generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I have the following extension methods:

```
public static class QueryableOptionalDateRangeExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> StartsFrom<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IOptionalDateRange // Might also be IRequiredDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.Start >= date);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> StartsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IOptionalDateRange // Might also be IRequiredDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.Start < date);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> EndsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IOptionalDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.End <= date);
    }
}

public static class QueryableRequiredDateRangeExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> StartsFrom<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IRequiredDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.Start >= date);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> StartsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IRequiredDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.Start < date);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> EndsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
        where T : IRequiredDateRange
    {
        return query.Where(obj => obj.End <= date);
    }
}
```

This however does not work since it can't infer the overloading from the type of T for some reason (although it seems possible to me).
What can be done to work around this issue?

EDIT:
Here's the IDateRange interface:

```
public interface IDateRange<TStart, TEnd>
{
    TStart Start { get; set; }
    TEnd End { get; set; }
}
```

It just specifies that the class has a start and an end.
Now I want it to specify whether the object has an optional date range (both start and end are nullable) or a required date range (both are value types) but the same extension method must work on both and I don't really want to specify the Start and End properties' types.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Already done, but IDateRange has two generic parameters for the Start & End properties (they might be nullable or not) and then you can't compare T to datetime.

Comment: Please post it as a comment to my answer - I will answer your comment there.

Comment: You should think about that design. Your `IDateRange` says it is a date range, still, I could put anything in there, e.g. I could create an `IDateRange<Guid, HttpContext>`...

Comment: You still haven't shown what's actually happening. A short but *complete* piece of code showing a single method declaration (rather than 4) and something trying to use it would be helpful.

Comment: Surely the property types must be DateTime ? You are comparing them to  DateTime in the extension method body so why would you allow other types?

Comment: @Peter yes, but the date time can be nullable as well.

Comment: Okay, to me that says the design needs to be re-thought (see my updated answer). Opening it up to any types just to support optional or required (a yes/no flag) doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Peter: Exactly. That's what I was trying to say earlier...

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "does not work". Were you expecting overload resolution (including finding extension methods) to take account of the constraints? If so, that doesn't happen - I've written a [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/) going into the details of this.

That's possibly why what you're trying isn't working - although as you haven't given an example, it's hard to say for sure. As for how to *fix* it - I would suggest using different method names, e.g. `MaybeStartsFrom` for the optional range. If you could give a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve, that would help...

Answer (score 2):

Make both `IRequiredDateRange` and `IOptionalDateRange` inherit from `IDateRange` and put the `Start` and `End` properties there. What you are trying can't be achieved otherwise, because "generic method type inference deliberately does *not* make any deductions from the constraints", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171067/no-type-inference-with-generic-extension-method/7171527#7171527).

Answer (score 0):

You could move them into separate namespaces but that would be BAD. It is fragile because changing namespaces could result in different behaviour (unexpectedly). Plus this won't work if you need to use both methods in the same file (as pointed out by Daniel).

---

Okay, so after reading your update why don't you add an `IsDateOptional` property to your `IDateRange` interface, define the date types as `DateTime` getting rid of the generic element to that interface. There is now no need for two separate interfaces `IOptionalDateRange` and `IRequiredDateRange`... and you can replace the two extension classes with one.

```
    public interface IDateRange
    {
        DateTime Start { get; set; }
        DateTime End { get; set; }
        bool IsDateOptional { get; }
    }

    public static class QueryableDateRangeExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> StartsFrom<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
            where T : IDateRange
        {
            return query.Where(obj => obj.Start >= date);
        }

        public static IQueryable<T> StartsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
            where T : IDateRange
        {
            return query.Where(obj => obj.Start < date);
        }

        public static IQueryable<T> EndsUntil<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime date)
            where T : IDateRange
        {
            return query.Where(obj => obj.End <= date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's the way to extend IQueryable and make date range comparisons more comprehensible.

Comment: "You could move them into separate namespaces". This failes as soon as he needs both in the same file.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Which is why I said it was BAD :)

Comment: I know that you said it. But you didn't say why ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, it T is always "IOptionalDateRange" in the methods of QueryableOptionalDateRangeExtensions, why make it generic in the first place?

Second, it seems the IOptionalDateRange interface simply extends the IRequiredDateRange interface (I guessed that because your wrote IOptionalDateRange might also be IRequiredDateRange). That means, if an object implements IOptionalDateRange, it also implements IRequiredDateRange. How do you expect the compiler to differentiate?

So solve this, the interface should not inherit each other, instead they could share a common base class.

Comment: Because T must be the concrete type in order to be used in IQueryable. Both IOptionalDateRange and IRequiredDateRange inherit from IDateRange<TStart, TEnd>. I wrote that the constraint matches both IRequiredDateRange and IOptionalDateRange.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET 4 and implement the interfaces with classes (not structures), you can take advantage of covariance and make the methods non-generic.  Instead you would have

```
IQueryable<IOptionalDateRange> EndsUntil(this IQueryable<IOptionalDateRange> query, DateTime date)
IQueryable<IRequiredDateRange> EndsUntil(this IQueryable<IRequiredDateRange> query, DateTime date)
```

Comment: That would be the accepted answer if I were on .NET 4. However I'm not sure how NHibernate would take this. I believe that it will still cause an error.