# C# generic constrain : type cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No type inference with generic extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171067/no-type-inference-with-generic-extension-method)

I have a generic function with constrain which returns the first object in a collection:

```
static T first<T, L>(L list) 
where L : ICollection<T>            
where T : SomeType
{
        T r = default(T);
        if (list != null && list.Count>0)
        {
            if (list.Count == 1)
            {
                r = list.First();
            }
            else
            {
                //throw some exception ...
            }
        }
        return r;
 }
```

But when I use it against a collection the code won't compile and give me a "type cannot be inferred from usage" error:

```
ICollection<SomeType> list = funcReturnCollectionOfSomeType();
SomeType o = first(list);
```

Could not figure out why, is there anyone can help? Thank you.

Comment: Especially see [Eric's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7171527/572644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't infer the type T backwards from the type L. Use a single generic parameter:

```
static T first<T>(ICollection<T> list) 
where T : SomeType
{
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. A little bit disappointed though, in java it is possible.